# How would I write to an existing login process in linux (ie the one that shows up default on the display)?

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, tty

I am programming a simple app to display data on a small display connected to a raspberry pi via its RCA adapter.  On start-up it goes to the standard Linux login prompt.  I do not have a keyboard attached to the device.

Since the resolution is really bad, I would like a way to write to the login prompt that comes up on the monitor when it starts up via SSH to login, or hijack the process that shows the login prompt to write raw text to it.

Is there a simple way to do this?  Sorry if I am being unclear, unsure of the proper verbiage to ask this question.

Comment: Sorry, but do you want to connect via SSH? You can use any SSH client to do that. I still don't get what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to use SSH from another computer to control the process that is showing up on the display connected to the raspberry pi.